# Why does this SVG fragment identifier in CSS not get rendered when manipulated onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an SVG image sprite made up of two states of a checkbox. I created two group IDs in the SVG file so I could change the SVG viewBox by fragment identifier on click.

When I try to switch the class name to "checked" it does not re-render the checkbox to the correct state, unless I do something to force a re-paint (such as resizing the window).

This works in Firefox but not Chrome (v56). I can get it to work by changing the display:; property in the "checked" class but just curious  what exactly is going on here.

Codepen here to play around:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/evGWPj

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="check" id="check">
        Click me
    </div>
    <p>Then, resize the viewport</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.check {
  background-image:url("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/static.musomatt.com/misc/checkbox.svg#unchecked");
  background-size:18px;
  background-position:10px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left:40px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.checked {
  background-image:url("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/static.musomatt.com/misc/checkbox.svg#checked");
}
```

**JS**

```
var el = document.getElementById("check");
el.addEventListener("click", toggleCheck);

function toggleCheck(){
  el.classList.toggle("checked");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is the `background-position` property.

To fix this without changing the `display` property, change the background position in one of the two classes.

The two classes must not share the same `background-position` value.

**Example:**

In your `.checked` class include:

```
  background-position: 10.01px center;
```

---

```js
var el = document.getElementById("check");
el.addEventListener("click", toggleCheck);

function toggleCheck() {
  el.classList.toggle("checked");
}
```

```css
.check {
  background: url("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/static.musomatt.com/misc/checkbox.svg#unchecked") 10px center no-repeat / 18px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checked {
  background-image: url("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/static.musomatt.com/misc/checkbox.svg#checked");
  background-position: 10.01px center;
}
```

```html
<div class="check" id="check">
  Click me
</div>
```